# If I have become signed out during an edit, stop an edit submission with an error without redirecting

Tags: feature-request, edits

Today I edited some else's question, and notice that when it redirected it had put the edit in the Review Queue from an anonymous user. I was signed in at the time of clicking the edit button, but had become signed out, possibly because of a system upgrade in the background.

My workaround in this case was to edit-and-accept the change, since I have the reputation to do so.

In these circumstances the form knows I am starting the edit as an authenticated user, so could the edit system read that and respond with an AJAX error instead of pushing the change to the review queue? I'd be happy to re-sign in on another tab, and then click the save button again, which would make this workflow easier.

If it makes a difference, I sign in using Stack Overflow SSO.